# The number of submodules of $M\oplus M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ is a simple $R$-module. Then what we can say about the number of submodules of $M\oplus M$?

1. it can be infinite
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4

I say that if $N$ be a submodule of $M\oplus M$, then for projective homomorphisms $\pi_{1}$ and $\pi_{2}$, there exist two cases for each them.

Comment: Aliye +1 Ali jan

Comment: sepas az shoma doste aziz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Ask yourself how many $\Bbb R$ subspaces $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ has.